# Count records with same id but different column value

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have the following table:

```
+------+------+
|userID|Name  |
+------+------+
|1     |sport |
+------+------+
|2     |it    |
+------+------+
|3     |game  |
+------+------+
|1     |sport |
+------+------+
|1     |game  |
+------+------+
|3     |it    |
+------+------+
|3     |sport |
+------+------+
|2     |it    |
+------+------+
```

I want to count the total number of records per UserID and if all of those are unique/have the same Name.
Example:

- userID 1: sport, sport, game
- userID 2: it, it
- userID 3: game, it, sport

I should get:

- userId 1: 3, False
- userID 2: 2, True
- userID 3: 3, False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total number of rows per `UserID` is easy, you just need to use `COUNT(*)`. As for the other column, then, assuming `Name` cannot be null, you need to count distinct `Name` values and compare the result to 1. To explain: if all names are identical, `COUNT(DISTINCT Name))` will return 1, otherwise it will return a different number. Thus, by comparing the result to 1 you will determine whether all names are unique or not.

This is how I would implement it in SQL:

```
SELECT
  UserID,
  COUNT(*)                   AS TotalRows,
  (COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = 1) AS AllNamesUnique
FROM
  YourTable
GROUP BY
  UserID
;
```

Feel free to play with this solution [at dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=fd0b3f0d1d4f73e455ec1090546f353b).

Comment: Very neat Andriy! +1